# Why does a blur filter with a transition have some lag and problem?

Tags: html, css

After hovering on an image, I have a white lag in the edges of the image and then this will be hidden!!! How can I fix this?

The code is here:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    @include transition_all(0.3s);
}

img:hover {
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
}

<a href="assets/images/portfolio/1.jpg" class="portfolio-item images" data-featherlight="image">
    <div class="portfolio-item-wrap">
        <img src="assets/images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="portfolio title"/>
        <div class="desc">
             <h5>Gallery</h5>
             <h4>Fruits Images</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well, so we can test it. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it is a img tag on isotope js gallery file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blur filter is quite heavy on resources, and you can't do anything about it. I usually avoid using blur filters for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using `filter:blur(10px)`, use `filter:blur(2px)`.
This is a great way of reducing lag in HTML.